# List files in ascending order and greater than a given value

Tags: shell, ls

I have some log files which has a standard prefix.

```
dev-app.0001
dev-app.0002
dev-app.0003
dev-app.0004
dev-app.0005
dev-app.0006
dev-app.0007
dev-app.0008
```

I have a metadata file which has when this log file created.

For eg: at `5AM dev-app.0005 is created`. I want to list the files in ascending order which are greater than dev-app.0005.

#### Expected output:

```
my_file=dev-app.0005
```

#### list files which are greater than or equal to $my_file

```
dev-app.0005
dev-app.0006
dev-app.0007
dev-app.0008
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 my_file=dev-app.0005
 ls -1 | sed -n "/$my_file/,//p"
```

- `-1` Prints one entry per line of output for `ls`.
- `sed -n '/dev-app.0005/,//p'` will print all after matching pattern `dev-app.0005`

Answer (score 1):

Try also (stealing from msp9011's post)

```
$ read TIME my_file REST < metadatafile
$ ls dev* | sed -n "/$my_file/,\$p"
dev-app.0005
dev-app.0006
dev-app.0007
dev-app.0008
```

Answer (score 1):

bash, with `shopt -s extglob`: all files except the 4 you don't want:

```
ls !(dev-app.000[1-4])
```

See [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)
in the bash manual.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below method using awk and it worked fine

```
for i in `cat filename`; do k=`echo $i|awk  -F "" '{print substr($NF,1,1)}'`
> if [[ $k -ge 5 ]]
> then
> echo $i
> fi
> done

output

dev-app.0005
dev-app.0006
dev-app.0007
dev-app.0008
```

Answer (score 0):

Im answering my own question. I found another simple way.

```
ls | grep dev-app.| awk '$1 >= "dev-app.0005"'
```

Comment: Why the `grep`? `awk` can match patterns as well.